# Reversing a list slice in python

Tags: python, reverse, slice

I am trying to reverse slice of a list in python but it returns an empty list. But when I try with whole list, it works fine. Am I missing anything here?

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l[::-1] = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]     # <<< This worked fine.

l[2:5] = [3, 4, 5]
l[2:5:-1] = []       # <<< Expecting [5,4,3] here.
```

Any clues?

Comment: `l[2:5][::-1]` Doing it in different square brackets, it works.

Comment: you would need `l[4:1:-1]` using a negative step. -1 is not reversing it is stepping

Comment: @PadraicCunningham why doesn't this work though as `l[2:5:2]` does work I'm intrigued

Comment: @EdChum,  you are starting at `2` and stepping `-1` trying to get to `5`, it makes no sense to step from  2 to 5 going backwards

Comment: Because you're trying to count backwards from 2 to 5.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ahh OK, if you'd assigned the slice then it works fine :`p=l[2:] p[::-1]` I'd presumed that the indices would've become anonymous index values so stepping would just work

Answer (score 9):

The syntax is always `[start:end:step]` so if you go backwards your start needs to be greater than the end. Also remember that it includes start and excludes end, so you need to subtract 1 after you swap start and end.

```
l[5:2:-1]= [6, 5, 4]
l[4:1:-1]= [5, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slice notation is `[start:stop:step]`. This means "begin at `start`, then increase by `step` until you get to `end`." It's similar to this construct:

```
counter = 0
stop = 10
step = 1
while counter < stop:
    print(counter)
    counter += step
```

This will produce, as expected, `0` through `9`.

Now imagine if we tried it with the values you're using:

```
counter = 2
stop = 5
step = -1
while counter < stop:
    print(counter)
    counter += step
```

If we actually executed this, it would print `2`, then add `-1` to that to get `1`, then print `1` and add `-1` to that to get `0`, then it would be `-1`, `-2`, and so on, forever. You would have to manually halt execution to stop the infinite loop.

If you leave `start` or `stop` empty, as in `[:4]` or `[::-1]`, this indicates the beginning or end of the sequence, as determined by the `step`. Python will go forwards with a positive `step` and backwards with a negative `step` (trying to use a `step` of `0` produces an error).

```
>>> l[2::]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> l[2::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>> l[:2:]
[1, 2]
>>> l[:2:-1]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
```

If you specify a `start`, `end`, and `step` that couldn't work (an empty `step` defaults to `1`), Python will simply return an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**Why does `L[::-1]` return a reversed list, but `L[2:5:-1]` an empty `[]` one???**

##### The core of the confusion is the *(wrong)* assumption that in the   *`[start:stop:step]`* slice a missing start value will always be set to the beginning (the start) and the missing stop value to the end of a list.

**This assumption is not true because in Python if you don't explicit specify   *`start`* and *`stop`* Python will substitute the missing *`start`* and *`stop`* values differently depending on the sign of *`step`*, setting the *`start`* to the end of the list, not the beginning, in case of a negative *`step`* value.**

When you don't specify the *`start`* and/or *`stop`* values in a slice *`L[start:stop:step]`* (i.e. use *`L[::step]`*) Python will behave as follows :

- if *`step`* has a **positive value** than *`start`* will be set to `0` zero ( and *`stop`* to `len(L)` )
- if *`step`* has a **negative value** than *`start`* will be set to `len(L)-1`. Which value will be assigned to *`stop`* if it isn't specified can't be expressed in terms of slicing and would need conversion of slice defining values to parameters of `range()`.

The different cases of handling not explicitly specified slice values and the feature allowing usage of negative values for indices in slices is coded in Python source code with multiple `if` statements which finally define the slice behavior. So to fully understand Python slicing you have to know how they are coded. And because there does not exist one and the only one making sense straightforward rule for coding slice behavior, the chosen set of decisions for designing slices does not always directly meet ones intuitive expectations.

---

Let's provide some code to prove the above to be true along with another ways of explaining the same as already stated above (see comments in code). The code below uses Pythons `assert` statement to check if the given comparisons show the right sliced values and the in Python for `slice` objects available `.indices()` method giving the parameters for `range()` returning the required list indices representing by the slice object:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
assert L[ : :  ]    == [1,2,3,4,5,6] # << OK. No AssertionError.
assert L[ : :-1]    == L[len(L)-1:-len(L)-1:-1] == [6,5,4,3,2,1]
assert L[ : :-1]    == [6,5,4,3,2,1] # << OK. No AssertionError.
assert L[2:5:  ]    == [3,4,5]
# ===
assert L[2: :-1]    == [3,2,1]
# ^-- because with -1 step and decreasing i -= 1 starting with 0  
# ^-- the condition (2+i > -1) for list index gives [3,2,1]
assert slice(2,None,-1).indices(len(L)) == (2,-1,-1)  
# ^-- and because the None becomes -1 ( for use in range() ) 
# ===
assert L[ :5:-1]    == []
# ^-- because with -1 step and decreasing i -= 1 starting with 0  
# ^-- no list item will meet the condition (2+i > 5) for its index  
assert slice(None,5,-1).indices(len(L)) == (5,5,-1)  
# ^-- and because the None becomes 5 ( for use in range() ) 
# ===
assert L[2:5:-1]    == [] 
# ^-- because with -1 step and decreasing i -= 1 starting with 0  
# ^-- no list item will meet the condition (2+i > 5) for its index  
assert slice(2,5,-1).indices(len(L)) == (2,5,-1)  
# ^-- and because range(2,5,-1) does not return any values 
# ^-- and because you are starting at 2 and stepping -1 trying to get 
#     to 5 ( you can't count backwards from 2 to 5 ) 
# ===
assert L[2:5][::-1] == [5,4,3] # it works in different square brackets 
assert L[4:1:-1]    == [5,4,3] # '-1' is not reversing, it is stepping
```