# How does [...,::-1] work in slice notation?

Tags: python, opencv, slice

OpenCV uses BGR encoding, and `img[...,::-1]` swaps the red and blue axes of `img` for when an image needs to be in the more common RGB. I've been using it for several months now but still don't understand how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing a list slice in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085912/reversing-a-list-slice-in-python)

Comment: pretty sure opencv uses [numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) for the image: the ellipses are shorthand for any axes that *fit* in that context - and the `::-1` reverses the rows in a 2-d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slice operator works as with 3 params. Start(inclusive), end(exclusive) and step.
If start is not specified then it gets the start of the array, same with the end but with the last element. If step not specified the default is 1.

This way, if you do `[1, 2, 3, 4][0:2]` it will return `[1, 2]`

If you do `[1, 2, 3, 4][1:]` it will return `[2, 3, 4]`

If you do `[1, 2, 3, 4][1::2]` it will return `[2, 4]`

For negative indexes, that means iterate backwards so `[1, 2, 3, 4][::-1]` says, from the starting element until the last element iterate the list backwards 1 element at a time, returning `[4, 3, 2, 1]`.

As the question is not entirely clear I hope this clears up the functioning and make you get to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`img[...,::-1]` reverses the order of the 3 R,G,B components of the image

here is a numerical example

```
import numpy as np

#define  2x2x3 matrix with random numbers
A = np.random.randint(0,10,(2,2,3))
print(A)
#output
array([[[0, 1, 7],
       [9, 6, 6]],

       [[8, 2, 2],
       [7, 9, 4]]])
#print the third 2x2 component of A (corresponding to B in RGB)
print(A[:,:,2]
#output is 
array([[7, 6],
      [2, 4]])
```

now reversing the third dimension of the matrix will swap 0(R) with 2 (B) and keep 1 (G) unchanged

```
RA =A[:,:,::-1]

print(RA)
#output is 
array([[[7, 1, 0],
       [6, 6, 9]],

       [[2, 2, 8],
       [4, 9, 7]]])

#here is the first
print(RA[:,:,0])
#output is as expected the same as A[:,:,2], i.e. R and B were swapped
array([[7, 6],
      [2, 4]])
```

PS. `[:,:,1]` is the same as `[...,1]`