# Why does extended slicing not reverse the list?

Tags: python, list

I'm slicing lists in python and can't explain some results.
Both of the following seem natural to me:

```
>>>[0,1,2,3,4,5][1:4:1]
[1, 2, 3]

>>>[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[::-1] == [5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

However,

```
>>>[0,1,2,3,4,5][1:4:-1]
[]
```

thought I expected it to be [3,2,1]. Why does it produce [ ]? Why does it not reverse the list? What happens first inside python, the step or the slicing?

I also found that

```
>>>[0,1,2,3,4,5][-3:-6:-1]
[3,2,1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: The intuition I use for this is that in thinking of `[start:stop:step]`, both `[start:stop]` and `step` must be in the same direction. The same way you can't, while counting out loud, count starting at 1 and ending at 5 by counting backwards

Comment: Duplicate: [Reversing a list slice in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085912/reversing-a-list-slice-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The third number in the slice is the step count. So, in `[0,1,2,3,4,5][1:4:-1]`, the slicing starts at `1` and goes DOWN by `1` until it is less than `4`, which is immediately is. Try doing this:

```
>>> [0,1,2,3,4,5][4:1:-1]
[4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are slicing this then slicing will look like this `[start:end:step]`. For this one:

```
>>> [0,1,2,3,4,5][1:4:1]
[1, 2, 3]
```

It is staring from index 1 to index 3 because it exlcudes the index 4 with 1 step at a time. 
You are getting an empty list in the second one because you are stepping -1 from 1st index. So this will be the solution.

```
>>> [0,1,2,3,4,5][4:1:-1]
[4, 3, 2]
```

This works because you are taking an index from 4 to one with -1 step forward.