# Strange behavior with python slicing

Tags: python, list, slice

Suppose we have this list:

```
>>> a = [x for x in range(10)]
>>> print(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Separately, both ways to slice work as expected:

```
>>> a[3:8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

>>> a[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

But, when combined:

```
>>> a[3:8:-1]
[]
```

I would expect it to be `[7, 6, 5 ,4, 3]` or perhaps `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` (if reversing happened first).
It is also interesting to consider what happens when either `start` or `stop` parameters are not passed:

```
>>> a[:5:-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

This is almost what I would expect, only its one item short. Tested this with `numpy` and it seems to behave in the same way.

Whats going on here?

Comment: Did you try `a[8:3:-1]`?

Comment: if you had correctly understood first two expressions `a[:: -1]` and `a[3:8]` *then* your expected result should come from `a[3: 8][:: -1]` expression, rather than `a[3: 8: -1]`

Comment: Also: [Why does extended slicing not reverse the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56959836/7851470)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With

```
a[3:8:-1]
```

The start and stop positions of the slice aren't adjusted based on the step. With a negative step, you're having it go backwards from 3, but there are no elements with indices in the range 3 to 8 counting back from 3, so you get an empty list.

You need to set the start and stop accordingly:

```
a[8:3:-1]
```

Which will count back from 8 to 4.

Answer (score 7):

`a[3:8:-1]` instructs python to start from 3 and go to 8 by steps of -1

This creates an empty list: it's not possible to reach 8 from 3 by adding `-1` (just like `list(range(3,8,-1))` which gives an empty list too)

When you do `a[:5:-1]` then start is the default start, which python sets to "end of list" so it "works"

Same as when you do `a[::-1]` the start & stop are the default ones, and python understands that they're from end to start (else this notation wouldn't be useable)

Comment: Why would python set the start to "end of list" when doing a[:5:-1]??
Shouldn't it be "start of list"?

Comment: since the step is negative, default start & stop are reversed. Else `[::-1]` notation would not work at all.

Comment: @user3105173 because, slice notation is for *convenience*. When the steps are reversed, the implied starts-end change accordingly

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

> The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j. If i or j is greater than len(s), use len(s). If i is omitted or None, use 0. If j is omitted or None, use len(s). If i is greater than or equal to j, the slice is empty.
>
> The slice of s from i to j with step k.... stopping when j is reached (but never including j). When k is positive, i and j are reduced to len(s) if they are greater. When k is negative, i and j are reduced to len(s) - 1 if they are greater. If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k).